# Rate of approximation of Legendre's constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Roughly how big is log(n)−(n/π(n))-1 is as a function on n? It asymptotically approaches zero, but given how long it took to figure out that Legendre's constant is exactly 1 it seems like it must approach very slowly.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is approximately $1/\log n$, which follows from the standard asymptotic formula
$$
\pi(x) = \frac x{\log x} + \frac x{(\log x)^2} + \frac{2x}{(\log x)^3} + O\bigg(\frac x{(\log x)^4} \bigg).
$$

Comment: Isn'it $1/\log n$? The 2 disappears when you invert the asymptotic formula.

Comment: Does the pattern of having successive approximations of powers of the log continue forever? If so, what are the coefficients?

Comment: @abx you're right, thanks :)

Comment: @BramCohen The best approximation to $\pi(x)$ is the [logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion), which does have an asymptotic series in negative powers of $\log x$.

Comment: I wouldn't call it the best approximation to  $ \pi(x) $, as the Riemann  $ R $ function is an even better one.

Comment: What a strange series approximation. Adding each additional term makes for an asymptotically better approximation, but for any given value of x adding up all the terms diverges.

Comment: @BramCohen you're right; actually such "asymptotic series" are, surprisingly, not that uncommon.